# Child ignores parent's width/height when child has margin applied to it to create spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the attached image. Essentially it's a very simple concept. It's a standard containing block which requires children blocks to be positioned inside of it.

That in itself I can achieve quite easily. The tricky bit I'm struggling with is applying the spacing (margins) to the child elements. When I apply margins to the children they space out as required but they overflow outside of the parent container.

How do I get the children to maintain their given dimensions (including their margins) but to also remain inside the parent width? It needs to be a responsive design so I need percentage dimensions for all elements/styles.

The CSS I've tried is below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#container {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:80%; height:20%;
background:blue;
box-sizing:border-box;
font-size:0;
}

.boxes {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:25%;
height:100%;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:#555;
border:solid 1px red;
text-align: center;
color:#FFF;
margin:2%; /* <- THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS ============= */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please create jsfiddle and add there styles and markup?

Comment: Then set the `width` to `21%` instead of `25%` *(where `21%` comes from `(100% - 4 * 2*2%) / 4`)*.

Comment: Sure, here you go --> [jsfiddle.net/yksqqben/](http://jsfiddle.net/yksqqben/)